# same Intent sent twice, FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, onNewIntent() not executing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

This is a bit weird.
I create an Intent in ClassA

```
                Intent notifcationIntent = new Intent();
                notifcationIntent.setClass(context,MyClass.class);
                notifcationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    String dbgTimestamp = new Long(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
                notifcationIntent.putExtra("dbgTimestamp",dbgTimestamp);
```

I log dbgTimestamp after its been created and it has a value of 1000

In MyClass.class I receive the Intent,  log dbgTimestamp (which shows me the exected value of 1000) and exit.  I have verified MyClass.onDestroy() is being executed.

So far so good.

Then ClassA executes again and build another Intent

```
                Intent notifcationIntent = new Intent();
                notifcationIntent.setClass(context,MyClass.class);
                notifcationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    String dbgTimestamp = new Long(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
                notifcationIntent.putExtra("dbgTimestamp",dbgTimestamp);
```

I log dbgTimestamp after its been created and it has a value of 2000

MyClass executes again, receives the Intent but according to the log dbgTimestamp STILL contains 1000

I don't understand why.

MyClass is being destroyed, and even if it wasn't it contains onNewIntent() for which the docs say:

"This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it."

but onNewIntent() is NOT being executed.

I'm a bit at a loss as to what's going on and how to correct it.

Comment: Are you producing a `PendingIntent` using `notifcationIntent`? If so, please post the code you are using to create the `PendingIntent`.